# Hibernate find entities not in a collection

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an entity `CategoryModel`. One of the properties is copied below:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CategoryModel> children;
```

How can I perform a query that will return all `CategoryModel` entities that are not in another `CategoryModel` entity's `children` collection (i.e. the root categories)?

Comment: Maybe you can't change the schema, but would a RootCategoryModel and CategoryModel be a more appropriate normalization for this? I don't know if it make solving your problem any easier though...just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to make relationship bidirectional and apply `IS NULL` at the "many" side:

```
SELECT c FROM CategoryModel c WHERE c.parent IS NULL
```

If you can't change relationship, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT c FROM CategoryModel p RIGHT JOIN p.children c WHERE p IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried using a bidirectional relationship and it always crashed on fetch through recursion. It would fetch the parent that would fetch the child that would fetch the parent and so on. I tried using the mappedBy annotation property on the OneToMany side to no avail.

Comment: Actually, what was crashing via recursion was the Json serializer as I had forgotten to include an ignore annotation on the parent property. Thanks for your help!